# my api function is in another file or directory i want to check my api response data in another file or directory in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I am New to React Native and Please ignore My English

I have create two files called Browse.js and Setting.js and I write my API functions in Browse.js and from that functions I navigate to setting.js and in setting.js. now I want to check response data from API which I have declare in browse.js and according to that data I want to render a block . for eg is "title"="admin" then render this .

this is My API function in Browse.js =

```
 RoleLogin(){
    // const { username, password, roles } = this.state;
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    // fetch("https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/validate_login_details"
    , {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      // body: JSON.stringify([{ username: username, password: password }]),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())

    .then((json) => {
      //login to check details from server and then display or navigate to another screen
      // if (json != "error")
      if (json != "error")
      // if (response && response.length && response[0].message != "error")
      {
        alert(JSON.stringify(json));
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings");
      } else {
        alert("Cehck Details");
      }
    })

    .catch((error) => alert("Cehck Details"));
  }
    //*******************navagte to setting when data fetch close**************************** */

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ categories: this.props.categories });
  }
```

and this my block in Setting.js which I want to render if title='something' or role='admin'

```
  {title == " " &&
            <Block row space="between" margin={[10, 0]} style={styles.inputRow}>
              <Block style={{ flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text gray2 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}></Text>
                <Foundation name="page-copy" size={24} color="black" />
                <Text bold style={{paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>Customer Report</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
            }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code?

Comment: yes sure i had updated please check

Answer (score 1):

You can send data while navigating through params.

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings",{data:apiData})
```

And on Setting.js you can receive params data in different methods depending upon ReactNavigation Version.
For version 5

```
let data = props.route.params?.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data as route props to other component at the time of navigation as follows:

```
  this.props.navigation.naviagte('ScreenYouWantToNavigate',{ data:dataToSend });
```

and access that data in target component as follows

```
  console.log(this.props.route.params.data);
```

Comment: should i need to add somthing in body for that "dataToSend"

Comment: dataToSend should contain all the data that you want to send to Next screen